# Can't get the correct folder structure while copying folders

Tags: windows, vbscript

I am using the below code to copy certain files along with their folder structure.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
objStartFolder = Arg(0)

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Set subFolders = objFolder.subFolders

For Each folder In subFolders
    If (folder.DateLastModified < (Now() -100 )) Then
        filesys.CopyFolder folder, Arg(1)
    End If
Next
```

But I am not getting the correct folder structure after copying.

This is my source folder structure:

```
\Folder1\
├──TestFile1.txt
└──TestFile2.txt
\Folder2\
├──TestFile3.txt
└──TestFile4.txt
```

And this is the structure I am getting after copy:

```
├──TestFile1.txt
├──TestFile2.txt
├──TestFile3.txt
└──TestFile4.txt
```

But if I have subfolder inside my source folder, the script is working fine.

Comment: `Arg(1)` -> `Arg(1) & "\"`

Comment: Addendum: [`robocopy`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) or [`xcopy`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254.aspx) are probably better tools for this job than a custom VBScript.

Comment: Thanks @AnsgarWiechers your 1st suggestion worked like a charm